# The Difference between Windows Installer (WUBI) and Live CD/USB Installing?

Tags: installation, usb, wubi, live-cd

again me.

I am having trouble while installing Ubuntu. as I remember, I downloaded Ubuntu about two years ago and it was really easy. Mainly because I used Wubi and everything was fine.

I installed it and restart the computer to choose what OS will run my computer and it work fine! For some reason after that, I had to uninstall Ubuntu. Now, I want to install it forever, but I wonder about what is the difference between Wibu and liveCD/USB download?

I read the instructions and I see that downloading by CD/USB is really hard, there are partitions, for example, which I even don't know what they are (English is not my native language :( )  and it is really easy to download with Wubi.

I just want to know, which is the best way to install Ubuntu?

thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows installer I only used it once. I believe it is designed to run in Windows and let you demo Ubuntu, or install it beside Windows, giving you a dual boot with Windows boot manager in control by default.  I don't think it lets you install Ubuntu overtop of Windows.

The live CD/USB install has two versions.  The regular version is a user friendly installer with a graphical interface, kind of like the Windows installer disk.

The alternate CD/USB installer, which ends the name of the file with 'alternate.iso' is a technical installer, with advanced features available.  I recommend you download, and prepare both images on disk, in case the standard, graphical installer ever fails you, or you need the advanced features available only on the alternate version, such as improved partition management, which is the only feature I've ever needed it for.

If you want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, use the WUBI installer.

If you use the Live CD/USB (or alternate installer) you can reformat your hard drive and install Ubuntu alone, or manage your partitions and dual boot.